# Server is having problems parsing the same cookie it issues

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I am running an express app that uses the out the box stack (cookie-parser, connect-session, etc). I am also using a i18n module that sets a cookie depending on the user's language. I am having a cookie issue where I am not sure whether I am sending the correct cookies, or if the server is having problems parsing them. Whenever I authenticate a user, it sends a cookie that looks like this

```
"language=en-US; Path=/, keystone.uid=s%3A5b4f9dc45e23fe02b4b24862%3ACzrzXyYInv7VKl5PaevC9Ynd1qJD72Ip%2BmCd7NynoxU.rGWyRaQecitVOH4vQpZTD1ThpvQ44BI%2BmzOF51kjSms; Max-Age=864; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 25 Jul 2018 19:07:02 GMT; HttpOnly, this.sid=s%3AappByhBNAo31t5RlBF9cd80lZcsQEjE3.o4Wq9o7bhpptCrcJt6XIh1jjKQgWPgibnoI8TDalkDk; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 25 Jul 2019 18:52:38 GMT; HttpOnly"
```

Now inside my app (its a react native app), I store that string unmodified and whenever I try sending it again (without the quotes) in the next request, my server cannot parse it, and only parses the language cookie. I've taken that same cookie and tried sending it through fiddler, and postman and it has the same problem. The only way I am able to successfully recall my session is if I only send

```
"this.sid=s%3AappByhBNAo31t5RlBF9cd80lZcsQEjE3.o4Wq9o7bhpptCrcJt6XIh1jjKQgWPgibnoI8TDalkDk;"
```

in the cookie.

So upon further testing I decided to download the Cookie parser module to test it individually and it indeed parses the entire cookie wrong. Anyone know whether that cookie string is really invalid to send back to the server? If it is, what can I modify to make it valid? I may have to end up writing a regex to extract the this.sid token and I am not really good with regular expressions so help with that will also be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, the first question is why are you manually sending cookies on the client?  Browsers handle that for you automatically.  The server sets the cookie in an http response, the browser receives that cookie and stores it.  Any future http requests sent to that same host will automatically include the previous cookie (unless it expires or has an incompatible host or path).

Comment: Like I mentioned, the interaction is between a react native app and my node.js server. There is a bug or more of a limitation within the native react native cookie manager and the workaround is to store the cookie at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the header I was getting the cookie from is the "Set-Cookie" header which is a different format than what the Cookie header should be. If you're facing similar issues in React Native there is a module that parses the Set-Cookie headers [Set-Cookie-Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-cookie-parser)